# A full dim. subvector space of $\chi^{\infty}(M)$ which all non zero elements are nonvanishing vec.field

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

What  is  an  example  of a $n$ dimensional   manifold $M$ which  is  not  a  lie  group or $S^{7}$ but  satisfies the  following  property?:

> There is  an $n$  dimensional   sub vector space $V\subset \chi^{\infty}(M)$ such that every $0 \neq X \in  V$ is  a  nonvanishing  vector  field  on $M$.

So  this is a  motivation to  define  an  invariant  of  manifolds  as  follows:
$$ \text{The  maximum number $k\leq n$ with a k dimensional subvector  space$$ $V\subset\chi^{\infty}(M)$  with the  above property} $$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These manifolds, which have a trivial tangent bundle, are called parallelizable. They include all open sets of $\bf R^n$, thus I assume that you had in mind closed (compact without boundary) manifolds.

There are still many closed parallelizable manifolds, the most famous being perhaps all three-dimensional orientable manifolds (Stiefel's theorem, see Milnor-Stasheff, *Characteristic classes*, Problem 12-B page 148). The simplest example is the product $S^1\times S^2$.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow, Jean-Claude!

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeSikorav  Thank you very  much for  the  answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this really a vector space?

Suppose it is. Consider a nonzero element $X$ of it. It's negative $-X$ is also there. Perform a tiny perturbation, contained in a small ball: $Y = -X + \varepsilon Z$, $supp(Z) \subseteq B_\delta(p)$. Then the sum $X + Y = -\varepsilon Z$ is not zero and vanishes everywhere outside of the ball!